# iterating list through multiple if statement in python

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I have a list and two values to compare:

```
mylist = [98, 10, 12]
w = 85
c = 90

for i in mylist:
    if i <= w:
        status = "OK"
    elif i >= w and i < c:
        status = "WARNING"
    elif i >= c:
        status = "CRITICAL"

print status
```

The condition is:
a) If all the elements in the list are less than w and c, should print OK.
b) If any of the elements is greater than w and less than c, should print WARNING.
c) If any of the elements is greater than c, should print CRITICAL.

This code prints OK, however should print CRITICAL.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, two `OK`s and three `CRITICAL`s are printed.

Comment: Either you're not showing us the actual code or you have a new and interesting definition of "stop".

Comment: is there maybe a `break` or `return` somewhere further in the actual loop? both would stop the loop from continuing.

Comment: So do you want the program to print "Ok", "Warning", and "Critical"?
The line that prints "WARNING" will never run as well.

Comment: It's hard to "correct the code" if it's not clear what the expected result is. This obviously prints "OK", "OK", "CRITICAL", "CRITICAL", "CRITICAL". Isn't that the intended result?

Comment: Your new description is still not exact: it is possible for both "any element greater than `c`" and "any element greater than `w` and less than `c`" to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the value for `status` each iteration so you are effectivly just checking the last element in the list and that's below `w` so it prints `OK`.

Given your approach an obvious way of fixing it would be to break the `for`-loop as soon as one value is critical and don't check for OK as soon as one element already triggered the warning.

```
mylist = [98, 10, 12]
w = 85
c = 90
status = 'OK' # assume it's ok until you found a value exceeding the threshold
for i in mylist:
    if status == 'OK' and i < w: # Only check OK as long as the status is ok
        status = "OK"
    elif i >= w and i < c:
        status = "WARNING"
    elif i >= c:
        status = "CRITICAL"
        break # End the loop as soon as a value triggered critical

print status
```

---

Aside from the proposal I would suggest just finding the `max` value and compare it:

```
maximum = max(mylist)
if maximum < w:
    status = 'OK'
elif maximum < c:
    status = 'WARNING'
else:
    status = 'CRITICAL'
```

Comment: The suggestion to use `max` is really the best answer there can be for this question. No need to check every value if you only care about the highest status value.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
def check(mylist):
    w, c = 0.85, 0.90
    if any(x >= c for x in mylist):
        # there is an element larger than c
        return "CRITICAL"
    elif any(x >= w for x in mylist): 
        # there is an element larger than w
        return "WARNING"
    else:
        return "OK"
```

then:

```
>>> check([98, 10, 12])
'CRITICAL'
```